# App crashes on start before asking for permissions

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

I m trying my app but when i install the apk in my phone at first start it show permissions fast and crashes and when i restart it show permissions and i check Ok and its ok.

Please how to prevent that? becauses some of all users will not restart the app a second time! thank you

This is my permissions : (Probleme is only in  Record Audio, Access to files)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL" />
```

Informations about project :

minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 26
compileSdkVersion 26

Thank you so much

This the Error in error logs:

```
11-21 17:46:17.298 24237-24647/com.geniusly.myapp E/Message_Register: DONE
11-21 17:46:17.476 24237-24237/com.geniusly.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                 Process: com.geniusly.myapp, PID: 24237
                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=200, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.geniusly.myapp/tin.subtil.HomeActivityNew}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4481)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4524)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1691)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
                  Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
                     at tin.subtil.HomeActivityNew.onRequestPermissionsResult(HomeActivityNew.java:298)
                     at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7404)
                     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7230)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4477)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4524) 
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap22(ActivityThread.java) 
                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1691) 
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) 
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Edit :

This is my code :

```
private boolean permissionToRecordAccepted = false;
private boolean permissionToWriteAccepted = false;
private String[] permissions = {"android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO", "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};
```

in (onCreate)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_new);

    int requestCode = 200;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
    }

    init();
    myHandler = new Handler();
    slidingUpPanelLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.HIDDEN);
    SetupToolbar();
    SetupPager();
    SetupDrawer();
    iv_playpause.setTag("pause");      
    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), 
    getResources().getString(R.string.admov_id));
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Here RequestPermissions :

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 200:
        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            permissionToRecordAccepted=true;
        }
        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            permissionToWriteAccepted=true;
        }

        break;
    }
    if (!permissionToRecordAccepted) HomeActivityNew.super.finish();
    if (!permissionToWriteAccepted) HomeActivityNew.super.finish();
}
```

Comment: put your initial activity code

Comment: Can you post some code and a stacktrace of the crash

Comment: please check your log, the error its  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException check your array

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0` You're dealing with an **empty array**.

Comment: I edited the question with code , please any help the error is : that app crashes at same time of asking for permissions. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On all versions of Android, your app needs to declare both the normal and the dangerous permissions it needs in its app manifest, as described in Declaring Permissions. However, the effect of that declaration is different depending on the system version and your app's target SDK level:

If the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target SDK is 22 or lower: If you list a dangerous permission in your manifest, the user has to grant the permission when they install the app; if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install the app at all.
If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher: The app has to list the permissions in the manifest, and it must request each dangerous permission it needs while the app is running. The user can grant or deny each permission, and the app can continue to run with limited capabilities even if the user denies a permission request.
Note: Beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), users can revoke permissions from any app at any time, even if the app targets a lower API level. You should test your app to verify that it behaves properly when it's missing a needed permission, regardless of what API level your app targets.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

    int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Permission to record denied");
        makeRequest();
    }
}

protected void makeRequest() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
            RECORD_REQUEST_CODE);
}



Next, implement the onRequestPermissionsResult() method so that it reads as follows:




@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                   String permissions[], int[] 
 grantResults) {
switch (requestCode) {
    case RECORD_REQUEST_CODE: {

        if (grantResults.length == 0
                || grantResults[0] != 
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Permission has been denied by user");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Permission has been granted by user");
        }
        return;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Kummar for your answer, so if i understand i have to code the ask for permissions in additions of manifest? 

Thank you

Comment: Yes @AmenzO you need to request for permission by calling set permission request if your device target Marshmallow and above.You are welcome and you can accept the answer if you are able to solve your problem

Comment: Thank you so much Kumar, I will try to learn more about that and try to code it i dont have the choice.

Comment: @AmenzO edited my answer for you to  get the way of handling permission in marshmallow and above

Comment: Hello Kumar , thank you so much, im sorry i did a mistake yesterday , there is a code to ask for permissions ( apologize) its that the source of error , how could i put my code here ? my activity code is 1500 lines istill get same error. thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

[**RxPermission**](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions) is best library which made code 1 line.

Then ask run time permission.

```
RxPermissions rxPermissions = new RxPermissions(this);
rxPermissions
.request(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) // ask single or multiple permission once
.subscribe(granted -> {
    if (granted) {
       // All requested permissions are granted
    } else {
       // At least one permission is denied
    }
});
```

add this library in your `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.tbruyelle:rxpermissions:0.10.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.1.1'
}
```

**Isn't this easy?**